# How to interact with cmd through a file?

Tags: django, cmd

### My commands.bat file contains:

py manage.py makemigrations ParameterManager

py manage.py migrate

py manage.py createsuperuser

---

These commands are executed. Now cmd asks for a username, email and password.

How do I answer to these questions from the file, without the need for user interaction?

[pip freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfDk1.png)

Comment: `py manage.py createsuperuser --no-input --username name_here --email email@email.com`. Password must be explicitly entered though.

Comment: This is the output:
"cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled
cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled
Superuser created successfully."

But it doesn't give the opportunity to write the password. So I can't access the superuser.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Which OS? Run `pip freeze` and paste the output (not as a comment here but append it to your question).